# How to trigger a calculate the time spent on an software using python?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

I am looking for a solution to keep track of the time spent on a software.

Thought of triggering a python script and calling the exe using its path indirectly.

But is it possible to trigger a python script on  opening an exe file ?

Say,  I am opening drRacket.exe,

On each session my python script that updates the time spent on the session 
must be triggered.

Also, I need to keep track of the exit time too ...

Comment: You mean how much time an executable takes to execute?

Comment: @Neo Nope,  I am trying to fetch the time that an exe file has been running

i.e till the application  is closed manually.

To be more precise,  i am trying keep track of the time that I spent on this application dr.racket exe which is a code editor.

I am planning to save each open and exit in a  text file.. Then compute the time  spent using another python script

Answer (score 1):

If you know, how to call your .exe from terminal, use the `os`-module to call it and use a simple timestamp to compare start- and endtime:

```
import os, time

start=time.time()
os.system("<command to start your script>")
print("spent time:",time.time()-start)
```

Comment: Does it matter whether the timer gets started with the exe or the exe with the timer? If not, you just need to start your text editor or what ever with this script (you could create a shortcut or an alias named by your application). By running the exe from an extra thread, you could do with it what you want (e.g. shutting it down). Isn't this what you asked for?

Comment: Thanks for this, I have this anyway.

But I am still looking for an answer to -
how to execute a script on start of an application?

To break it down,

ecah time that I open notepad.exe and  close it,
i need to update the time 

I have a soultion to call notepad from a python script

But I am looking for an answer to-
fire script on opening an application,

If i am going with the solution  that you described,
I must call a python script which in turn will update the time 
and then it starts my application